# Disease-causing allele frequency and modern medicine

Tags: genetics, immunology, population-genetics, medicine, human-evolution

I was thinking about what the impact modern medicine might have on human evolution based on a couple assumptions.

If we assume that:

1. modern medicine has massively cushioned the selection pressure against people with inborn errors of metabolism, weak immune systems, disabilities, and genetic defects more broadly.
2. that these people, due to modern medicine, are able to live past reproductive age.
3. and that these people (broadly speaking) go on to produce offspring at the same or marginally lower rate as those without these defects.

could we expect to see these defect-causing alleles increasing in frequency in the now and more so in the future? or maybe at some point, given the constant improvements in modern medicine, these alleles essentially become fixed in subpopulations or maybe even the global population?

Comment: Can you please provide a reliable source for the massive cushioning modern medicine has provided these individuals? Thanks.

Comment: I can't find any study, but surely its reasonable to assume it. And I don't think there will even be studies in this topic for the near future anyways, given that there is no benefit from researching this. But that doesn't mean its perfectly resonable. for instance,  as a higher percentage of people who would've died from infection are kept alive at least up until reproductive age.

Comment: Your three down votes and close votes would argue against your certainty. This site requires you show your attempts to answer your own questions. If you hover over the DVD’s button, one reason is “shows no effort”.

Comment: It's worth considering that other factors such as sanitation and a plentiful and reliable food supply play by far the most major part in decreased mortality, then other confounding factors such as pollution and increasingly sedentary lifestyles make it even more tricky to identify what effect medicine has.

Comment: @anongoodnurse https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64424/where-do-birds-and-squirrels-go-to-die and https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/do-air-purifiers-work-against-bacteria-and-viruses both did not cite anything. and maybe because it was phrased in anecdotal way. But my question is abstracted from anecdote, I HAVE a genetic defect and without modern medicine I'd die before reproductive age, no doubt about it. Besides, I never claimed that my assumptions were true, what I said was IF these assumptions WERE true, could we expect to see such alleles increasing in frequency

Comment: @JiminyCricket surely, in some contexts we can, take the sickle cell hypothesis, if my hypothesis is true, then we'd expect to see that west african populations with good access to antimalarial drugs, vaccines, and bed nets have gradually lower frequencies of sickle cell carriage or disease. Also, food supply generally doesn't affect the relative frequency of alleles, it increases population count but doesn't make those with genetic defects more likely to propogate (unless the defect impacts diet, e.g. the ability to fast)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I can't cite any direct evidence, but I will list you diseases that without modern medicine and scientific knowledge would've cut short peoples lifespan to before reproductive age or affected their reproducetive abilty. Phenylketonuria, Cystinuria, Glycogen storage diseases, Lysosomal storage disease, Leukemias, Type 1 diabetes, Asthma, neurofibromatosis, Fibrodysplasia ossificans progressiva, porphyrias, hemophilia, IgG deficiency, Haemochromatosis, and so on.  and this exludes infections, so my point stands. It's reasonable.

Comment: This question is strongly associated with the pseudoscience of eugenics, and specifically the idea of "dysgenics", supposing that modern interventions "weaken" the gene pool. I don't suggest this is your intention, I merely point out the connection. For more information I'd google "medicine dysgenics", which brings up scholarship such as [this](https://esrus.sites.stanford.edu/medicine-dysgenic). Trivially... sure, there is probably some effect. Substantially, it's not clear that this has much effect at all.

Comment: I believe @MaximilianPress has put it best. I also think you do not give credit to those with inborn errors of metabolism; most would not likely choose to procreate knowing that they are passing a fatal gene to their offspring. Anyone can claim anything on the internet. Did you know that I can fly? It’s an autosomal dominant mutation, obviously, because all of my children are good flyers as well. And the sun has no effect on our wings.

Comment: Finally, speaking as a physician, of the more than 1000 IEMs, only a metaphorical handful (not a massive cushion) can be treated with the individual reaching adulthood able to reproduce (for a variety of reasons). Some IEMs aren’t diagnosed until mid to late adulthood, so are probably common enough. Frame of reference is everything. Someone with a treatable IEM might win a Nobel prize someday for something that changes the world for the better. You never know.

Comment: @MaximilianPress I understand that that was always a possiblity because how easy it is to misinterpret what I'm trying to ask. But thank you, anyways for at least providing a use term, and an attempted answer, albeit without a source.

Comment: @anongoodnurse you bring up a good point, that people who are daignosed with genetic defects, IEM's, and disabilities might not choose to procreate. So the selection pressure is definitely not mitigated for alleles that cause those conditions. But I think there's definitely a grey area where negative selection is mitigated for those with alleles that cause mild to moderate disease that doesn't warrant genetic tests, which would also apply to polygenic traits like weaker immune systems, and certain mental disorders, for instance, but probably not to flying, though, sorry.

Comment: I’m so confused about what exactly it is that you’re asking… However, if you believe with any degree of certainty that medicine has massively cushioned the death rate from IEMs, why do you have difficulty believing that my offspring and I can fly? They’re about equally true…

Comment: @anongoodnurse I think you have missed my point. first of all, I'm not referring to IEM's across the board, nor am I referring to IEM's alone, I am saying modern medicine has massively cushioned negative selection pressure for CERTAIN ALLELES causing CERTAIN DISEASES. and therefore, WITH THE ASSUMPTIONS i have made, we should expect an increase in the frequency of such alleles. This is basic population genetics; removing or mitigating a selection pressure will cause alleles selected against to increase in frequency.

Comment: @anongoodnurse and who said I have difficulty believing you can fly, the traits practically fixed where I'm from ;) ,but you seem to have difficulty merely entertaining my position, perhaps its your ideology. Here's an example I'll try to explain, where I'm from Williams syndrome is underdiagnosed, and so what happens is only the resulting complication (usually cardiovascular) of Williams syndrome is treated, without the diagnosis of Williams syndrome being given. These treatments will prolong the life of the patient to at least reproductive age and so the alleles should increase in frequency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in principle, but it could take a very long time. Consider [phenylketonuria](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/phenylketonuria/symptoms-causes/syc-20376302), which is a severe genetic disease that is completely preventable by excluding phenylalanine from one's diet. Suppose that PKU is now completely neutral due to our ability to screen for PKU alleles and counsel carriers appropriately (not to avoid reproducing, which would induce selection against PKU, but to make sure that their children are tested and put on an appropriate diet).

How long will it take PKU to fix due to genetic drift?

From [here](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/genetic-drift-and-effective-population-size-772523/), the time to fixation

$$
E(T) = -4N_e [p \ln p + (1-p) \ln (1-p)] \textrm{ generations}
$$

where $N_e$ is the effective population size and $p$ is the starting frequency (this counts fixation at either 0% or 100% but should be a lower bound for fixation at 100%).

The highest frequency of PKU in any population in the world is around 70% (Gundarova et al. 2018); starting from here, the fixation time would be $0.63 N_e$ generations. Even in a very small population (e.g. $N_e = 200$), this will take hundreds of generations/thousands of years ...

The time scale might be much shorter if there were positive selection, i.e. some selective advantage to carrying the allele that also/formerly caused disease. This is known, or speculated, to be the case for many deleterious recessive alleles (sickle-cell, thalassemia, cystic fibrosis ...). However, in many of these cases the selective advantage is against infectious diseases such as malaria whose effects have *also* been mitigated by modern medicine ...

---

Gundorova, Polina, Rena A. Zinchenko, Irina A. Kuznetsova, Elena A. Bliznetz, Anna A. Stepanova, and Aleksander V. Polyakov. “Molecular-Genetic Causes for the High Frequency of Phenylketonuria in the Population from the North Caucasus.” PLoS ONE 13, no. 8 (August 1, 2018): e0201489. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0201489.